# how to map multiple routes in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having Home controller with default action as landing.

But for ErrorController default action should be index

In the RegisterRoutes method in Global.cs, I had written like this : -

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Landing", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

But when I am trying to redirect to error from Application_Error event : -

```
Exception error = Server.GetLastError();                    
string redirectUrl = "~/Error/id=" + errorId;
HttpContext.Current.Server.ClearError();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

it is throwing error - action landing not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another route above your current route for the more specific Error case:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Error", // Route name
            "Error/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Also, this looks a bit strange:

```
string redirectUrl = "~/Error/id=" + errorId;
```

Seems like it would be more this this:

```
string redirectUrl = "~/Error?id=" + errorId;
```

Comment: how about this - string redirectUrl = "~/Error/?id=" + errorId;

Comment: after adding additional routemap above the default route it throws error - "Value cannot be null or empty.\r\nParameter name: controllerName"

Comment: Are you adding the route above the default route? And changing the Route name?

Comment: yeah the same way you suggested

Comment: try to take out the `{action}` part of the uri template. `"Error/{{id}", // URL with parameters`

Comment: so in this case which action method it will execute in ErrorController?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your route mapping method *before* the other one, and it will give the error controller a different default action. Order is important here, routes are matched on a first-come, first-serve basis.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Error", // Route name
        "Error/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Error", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: after adding additional routemap above the default route it throws error - "Value cannot be null or empty.\r\nParameter name: controllerName"